# Passing by pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers

I have a question about passing via pointers in C. I will illustrate my question through this code snippet that I wrote:

```
int main () {
    List *head = (List *)malloc(sizeof(List));
    head->data = 0;
    head->next = NULL;
    insertEnd(head, 3);
    //List *temp = head;
    insertEnd(head, 4);
    PrintList(temp);
    return 0;
}

void insertEnd(List *node, int elem) {
    while (node->next != NULL) {
        node = node->next;
    }
    List *new_node = (List *)malloc(sizeof(List));
    new_node->data = elem;
    new_node->next = NULL;
    node->next = new_node;
}

void PrintList(List *node) {
    while (node) {
        printf ("%i ->", node->data);
        node = node->next;
    }
}
```

In the above code snippet, I create a List pointer called head, and pass it into my insertEnd() function two times. If you notice in my insertEnd() function, I am actually moving this passed in pointer along by doing a "node->next"

If I am changing the address this pointer points to within my insertEnd() function, then how come when I call PrintList() its as if the head pointers location never moved!

PrintList() returns: "0 -> 3 -> 4 ->"

Is this because when passing by pointer, you are actually passing a new physical copy of the pointer into the function, similar to passing by value, except in this case instead of copying over the entire value/data structure you simply copy over the pointer variable? I hope this makes sense..

Comment: Your explanation seems correct to me. You are passing the value of the pointer as a parameter, which allows you to change the data referenced by the pointer, but not the pointer itself.

Comment: Yeah thats what I thought but messing with C has got me second guessing my fundamentals. I mostly code in much higher level languages so its new to me

Comment: In addition: [do not cast the result of malloc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: @pzaenger why should I not do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Comment: @AyBayBay: Just check the link and read the accepted answer.

Comment: BTW normally it is better style not to use the argument to a function as a local variable and instead keep the original for reference. otherwise if the function gets more complex it may get a bit difficult to read.

Comment: Please, please, _please_, ***please***: do not cast the `void *` returned by `malloc` when writing C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, when you pass a pointer in a function argument the value of the address is copied so if you do :

```
void foo(int *f) {
    f = malloc(sizeof(int));
    printf("%d\n", f); 
}

void goo() {
   int *p = malloc(sizeof(int));
   foo(p);
   printf("%d\n", p);
}
```

they will print different results. This goes the same in your example when you pass `head` to the functions its address is copied to the `node` function argument. Changes to the values of `node` will not affect the value `head` (Only when you change the value pointed by these variables then if they point to the same address both `*head` and `*node` will show the same).